# store data table to object

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, backend

I have web app that I need store store data table to object
I have JavaScript code below that connect first to the database and SELECT table

```
//Connect to database
  var sql = require("mssql");

  var config = {
  user: '****',
  password: '*****',
  server: '****',
  databse:'****',
  options: {
      trustedConnection: true,
      trustServerCertificate: true
    },
  };
  
  sql.connect(config, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      // create Request object
      var request = new sql.Request();
      // query to the database and get the records
      request.query("select * from Test ", function (err, recordset) {
  
          if (err) console.log(err)
          // write the records in console.log
          console.log(recordset) 
   
      });
  });
```

below is the terminal output.

```
 recordset: [
    { ID: '1111      ', Name: 'Fahad     ', Age: '30        ' },
    { ID: '2222      ', Name: 'Omar      ', Age: '20        ' }
  ],
```

So I need to store the recordset to

```
var users = [{}]
```

when open the page on the browser the var users should look

```
users = [
    { ID: '1111', Name: 'Fahad', Age: '30' },
    { ID: '2222', Name: 'Omar', Age: '20' }
  ]
```

Comment: you can simply use localStorage API for this, first you need to stringify the data which is in the type array then you can store the data then next time when the user accessing the page you can convert the data to array with the help of JSON.parse()

Answer (score 0):

hope this example will help you

you can simply use localStorage API for this, first you need to stringify the data which is in the type array then you can store the data then next time when the user accessing the page you can convert the data to array with the help of JSON.parse()

```js
let data_to_store = [{user : "blob"}]

if(!localStorage.dataTableStored){
  localStorage.dataTableStored = JSON.stringify(data_to_store);
}
else{
    console.log("this data is stored in     localstorage",JSON.parse(localStorage.dataTableStored))
}
```

Comment: I have tried implement it to above code, but unfortunately no luck. I am trying my best but I have no back-end experience

Comment: this is front end code

Comment: tried to add code based on your instructions, but an err appear when run npm start                                  request.query("select * from [ISEEDB].[dbo].[Test] ", function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        // write the records in console.log
        console.log(recordset) 
        //add recordset to localstorage then get array back from localstorage 
        localStorage.setItem("recordset", JSON.stringify(recordset));
        var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("recordset"));
        console.log(storedNames);


    });

Comment: what is the error you are getting, if you are trying to parse empty string with JSON.parse() you will likely to get an err  so either use try catch or validation before parsing data. in my opinion try catch is better because even if the data is malformed it saves the day